# Firefox Extension - Need a specific div to ignore xhtml errors (mismatched tag, etc)

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

My firefox extension loads content from a 3rd party site into an overlay panel. This content is user generated and sometimes will, for instance, have an image tag that does not close  which causes a mismatched tag error to be thrown and the extension fails. Is there any way I can sandbox this content so that these kind of errors are not an issue? I was thinking maybe load the content into a blank iframed page.. but was wondering if there might be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Yes, the iframe sounds reasonable. Ensure it runs with the appropriate security context for the site it's coming from — you don't want user scripts to run with chrome privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, unless you're getting back XML, there is no XPCOM solution for parsing. Your best bet is what you suggested - placing the content in an iframe.

You can find some more discussion about the topic at: http://www.mozdev.org/pipermail/greasemonkey/2005-April/001255.html

Answer (score 0):

Your guess about an iframe was correct, there's no better way to do it (as of Firefox 3.5): [Parsing HTML From Chrome on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_HTML_From_Chrome)